# automatic variable 'trans' cannot be written in this context

Tags: system-verilog, test-bench

I tried to write systemVerilog simulation code. However, when I tried to write some value to class "trans", it show this error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

"trans" class has been included.

```
task main;
        forever begin
            transaction trans;
            gen2driv.get( trans );
            @( posedge vif.clk );
            vif.valid <= 1;
            vif.a <= trans.a;
            vif.b <= trans.b;

            @( posedge vif.clk );
            vif.valid <= 0;
            trans.c <= vif.c;

            @( posedge vif.clk );
            trans.display( "[ DRIVER ]" );
            no_transactions++;
        end
endtask
```

Error happens in line "trans.c <= vif.c".

It seems automatic variable 'trans' cannot be written. After I change 'trans' from automatic to global (static?), it worked. Anybody know why?

Comment: Error happens in line "trans.c <= vif.c".

Comment: It seems automatic variable 'trans' cannot be written. After I change 'trans' from automatic to global (static?), it worked. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

from the standard:

> It shall be illegal to make nonblocking assignments to automatic variables.

do not use nonblocking assignment `<=` on the automatic variable `trans`, use `=` instead. Or declare your `trans` outside your loop to make it static. Or declare it as `static`.